# UWP App store hidden app submission issue

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, uwp

I submitted my UWP app as a private visibility with only link download and on my dashboard it's showing up that the application is in publishing stage.
But when I go to "Submission 1" details it's showing that package is only submitted.

Also when I am trying to open that app link in my browser, it's displaying 
"We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found."

Also in my dashboard it's showing an update button, but if app is not published yet than how does an update button appear?
I am new to UWP, please guide me if I am misunderstanding something.
Please see for attached screenshot.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Your app is being published. Once the process is done your link will work and people will be able to download it. That doesn't mean that you can't update the packages right now. You shouldn't have to wait to, for example, for the app to be published to fix an issue you found today. If you update it now, the whole publishing process will start from scratch (meaning checks, validation and publishing).

Comment: Thanks, than will wait for the app to get live in store.

Comment: Added my comment as an aswer with more information and a useful link for you to check :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the whole certification workflow process in the [following link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/the-app-certification-process) but to sum it up the steps are as follow once your app is submitted:

1. Preprocessing
2. Certification
3. Release
4. Publishing
5. In the Store.

As of right now, your app is being published which means, once the step is done; the website link will be accesible and people will be able to download your app.

From the MSDN:

> After successfully going through the steps above, the submission's
>   status will change from Publishing to In the Store. Your submission
>   will then be available in the Windows Store for customers to download
>   (unless you have chosen another Distribution and visibility option).

Having said that, you are mixing the concept and flow of publishing an app with updating it. Basically, you are free to upload new packages for it whenever you want.

So for example, if you release a new major version of your app and realize, 5 minutes later; that it has a huge bug you can either remove the update from the store or update the packages with a different version.

It is worth mentioning that if you decide to update it, the whole certification process will start from scratch regardless of the step it was on.
Also worth mentioning is that if your app was already published and you release an update, even though the process starts anew, the "older" version will not be removed from the store until the new one passes the certification and the website will work as usual.

As a final note, before the publishing process begins, you can change (or update) some data regarding the release version of your app such as "Release date".